# JavaScript highlight substring(s) within string

Tags: javascript, html, string, function, substring

I have a JavaScript String which looks like this:

*From Windows to Linux*

With JavaScript, how can I highlight the words *From* and *Linux*, via a substring which looks like this:

*From Linux*

so the string looks like this in the end:

```
<mark>From</mark> Windows to <mark>Linux</mark>
```

This is my current implementation of the function to do that job:

```
  function highlightSearchTerm(string, substring) {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${substring})`, 'ig');
    return string.replace(regex, '<mark>$1</mark>');
  }
```

I call it like this:

```
highlightSearchTerm("From Windows to Linux", "from linux")
```

It works well, the only thing that is missing is to make it work when the substring has words which are not directly next to each other.

These substrings for instance work:

- *from windows*
- *From*
- *to Linux*

While these don't (Words are not directly next to each other in the main string):

- *Windows Linux*
- *from To*
- *Linux from*

Comment: How exactly are you calling `highlightSearchTerm` ?

Comment: hi @Jhecht, I call it like this:

`highlightSearchTerm("From Windows to Linux", "from linux")` for example.

I use svelte, so in the end the returned value just gets displayed as HTML.

Comment: try using `highlightSearchTerm("From windows to linux", "from|linux")` and lmk if that works

Comment: Hi, that seems to work. Why does that work?

Comment: excellent! I'll write out an explanation in an answer, give me a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Call `highlightSearchTerm()` with a pipe(`|`) between the terms to achieve the desired output.

### Longer Answer

The answer has to deal with how you are building your Regex.

The function

```
function highlightSearchTerm(string, substring) {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${substring})`, 'ig');
    return string.replace(regex, '<mark>$1</mark>');
  }
```

It's important to understand what the corresponding `RegExp` object that is created reads like, and how it equates to a form that we would maybe write out directly.

First, if we call

```
// assume substring = 'hello';
new RegExp(`(${substring})`, 'ig');
// Equivalent: /(hello)/ig;
```

Notice that the grouped item is looking for the word `hello`.

Now, if we supply something that has multiple things we want in it, such as `hi` and `you` then if we supply them as a single string separated by space, e.g.

```
const substring = 'hey you';
new RegExp(`(${substring})`,'ig');
// Equivalent: /(hey you)/ig
```

This will not give us what we want because instead of looking for `hey` or `you`, the parser is now looking `hey you` as a phrase.

However, if we separate those things by a pipe (`|`) we get

```
// assume substring = 'hey|you';
new RegExp(`(${substring})`,'ig');
// Equivalent: /(hey|you)/ig
```

This now looks for either `hey` or `you` in the string. This is because the pipe character in RegEx is the OR.

If you'd like to expand the search for multiple phrases, you separate each specific one by a pipe, e.g.

```
new RegExp('(hey|you|that guy)', 'ig');
```

Will search for the words `hey` and `you` and the phrase (space included) `that guy`.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. That makes sense :)

Do you think this solution is the shortest and most efficient it can get for highlighting a string with multiple words? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: i mean it is _a_ solution. You'll learn in programming that there are multiple different ways you could solve a problem, and you tend to use the one that makes the most sense for the problem. For what you are trying to do, this is likely fine.

Comment: Are you familiar with a bit of Svelte by any chance. I am asking because I have another function which is called `validateSearchTerm` and returns `true` if the substring is valid. And I would like to know if my current solution is overcomplicated. Maybe I should open another question for it.

Comment: I do in fact know a bit of svelte -- built a small Tauri app in it.

Comment: Sorry, my real question is: Can I somehow make the same which I just did with RegExp, but instead of returning a formatted string return true or false, depending on if the substring is within the original string?

Comment: if i understand it correctly then you would just store a reference to the  created `RegExp` object in a variable (say `reg` and then you should be able to use `reg.test(someStringVariable)` to test whether or not the substring is present. [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: You mean something like this, right?

`const formattedString = string.replace(regex, '<mark>$1</mark>');`

and then

`formattedString.test()`

Comment: no, apologies I'm not making myself clear. it is unfortunately late where I am and I am more tired than I think I realized. I'll come back in the morning and respond, but if you need help more urgently feel free to ask another question more inline with your end goal.

Comment: @John i have updated my solution so you can see how to check if your substring is included in your text

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pipe **|** just like @Jhecht explained above, alternatively you can **split** your **substring** and doing it this way:

```js
function highlightSearchTerm(string, substring) {
  let arr = substring.split(' ');

  arr.forEach(el => {
      const regex = new RegExp(el, 'ig'),
            temp = el;
            
      el = el.replace(regex, `<mark>${el}</mark>`);
      string = string.replace(temp, el);
  })
  return string;
}

let text = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML;

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = highlightSearchTerm(text, 'From Linux');
```

```html
<div>From Windows to Linux</div>
```

this is how you return **true** or **false** if your text includes the substring

```js
let text = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML;

function isIncludesSubstring(text, substring){
  let arr = substring.split(' '),
      arrResult = [];
  arr.forEach(el => {
    const regex = new RegExp(el, 'ig');
    arrResult.push(regex.test(text));
  });
  
  /* arrResult includes true or false based on whether substring single word
     is included in the text or not, the function will return true if all words are included
     else it will return false */
  return arrResult.includes(false) ? false : true;
}

console.log(isIncludesSubstring(text, 'From Windows Linux'))

console.log(isIncludesSubstring(text, 'To Windows from'))

console.log(isIncludesSubstring(text, 'From Test Linux'))
```

```html
<div>From Windows to Linux</div>
```

Comment: secret third option: combine our two answers and just replace the space character with the pipe character before making the regex

Comment: @Jhecht exactly, that's a nice Idea

Comment: Yes, this is my final solution now:

  function validateSearchTerm(string, substring, highlight = false) {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${substring.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, " ").split(" ").join("|")})`, 'ig');

    if (highlight) {
      return string.replace(regex, '<mark>$1</mark>');
    }

    return regex.test(string);
  }

Comment: you could simplify this code a bit by use the `Array.prototype.every` method instead of the `forEach` + `includes`. [MDN Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)